# Least square problem constrained to projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, projection

Some times in engineering, it is important to find an optimum subspace in which projecting on it satisfies some properties.

Let known matrices $A$ and $B$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$
and $\|\cdot\|_F$ be Frobenius norm.
How can I find the best subspace in which projecting $A$ on it is as close as possible to $B$?
In other words how can I find a solution to the following constrained optimization problem?
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\min_P \|PA-B\|_F^2 \\
 &&\mathrm{s.t. \ }P^T=P, \, P^2=P
\end{eqnarray}

---

Update:

I have incorporated the symmetry property ($P^T=T$) in objective function as follows. 
Since $P$ is symmetric, $P$ can decompose as $P=Y+Y^T$ where $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Now, the optimization problem reduces to 
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\min_Y \|C(Y+Y^T)-D\|_F^2 \\
 &&\mathrm{s.t. \ }\, (Y+Y^T)^2=Y+Y^T,
\end{eqnarray}
Where $C=A^T$ and $D=B^T$.

Further, using "vec" operator, we get
vec$(Y^T)=$$K$vec$(Y)$, where $K\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a unique and known matrix.
Using "Kronecker product", our optimization problem will be reduced to
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\min_y \|(I\otimes C)(I+K)y-d\|_2^2 \\
 &&\mathrm{s.t. \ }\, (Y+Y^T)^2=Y+Y^T,
\end{eqnarray}
where $y=$ vec$(Y)$ and $d=$ vec$(D)$.

Comment: Please [provide additional context,](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: This looks like just the [Orthogonal Procrustes Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem)

Comment: Not actually. The link you have sent, is talking about orthogonal matrices.
Here, I am talking about projection matrices!

Comment: This is reminiscent of (but not equivalent to) the [low-rank approximation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_Frobenius_norm))

Comment: Using SVD, we can reduce this to the case where $A$ (or $B$) is diagonal with non-negative entires.  Perhaps this is a useful simplification

Comment: How do you get the equivalence? If I have $B = U\Sigma V^*$ then $\Vert PA-B \Vert_F = \Vert U^*PAV - \Sigma \Vert_F$ but I'm not sure $U^*P$ is a projection matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how do you reduce it to the case where $A$ or $B$ is diagonal with non-negative entries.

Comment: @tch My mistake. We have
$$
\|PA - B\|_F = \|(U^*PU)(U^*AV) - \Sigma\|_F
$$
and $U^*PU$ is a projection.

Comment: Perhaps there's a nice approach with Largrange multipliers.  After all, both our objective function and constraints are differentiable